# How is the expected value of a function defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Currently I am reading into functional data analysis. A common assumption is that the expected value of some random function is $0$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(x) = 0$ where $x \in L^2$, the space of all squared integrable functions with inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = \int x(t)y(t) \text{d}t$.

My question might appear a little trivial to many of you, but I just want to be certain that I don't get this basic concept of zero expectation wrong: Does $\mathbb{E}(x) = 0$ mean, that $\mathbb{E}\left[x(t)\right] = 0 ~\forall t$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your last sentence does not make sense, there is no $t$ involved, and you essentially wrote "$\mathbb E(x)=0$ means that $\mathbb E(x)=0$".

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The question makes a lot of sense, since there is a big difference between $x$ and $x(t)$.

Comment: @AlexM.: please explain what $x(t)$ denotes IYO.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I am not sure, but I believe that you are making a notational mistake that many engineers and physicists do: you seem to think that $x$ and $x(t)$ both mean *"the function $x$ (which can be fed the argument $t$)"*. For mathematicians, the function is $x$ (or sometimes $x (\cdot)$), while $x(t)$ means *"the value of the function $x$ at the point $t$"*. With this explanation, the question does indeed make sense, because $\Bbb E (x(t)) = x(t) \Bbb E(1)$, which is different from $\Bbb E(x)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If you agree that there is a difference between $x$ and $x(0)$, then the same difference exists between $x$ and $x(t)$, for reasons of notational coherence.

Comment: @AlexM.: ok, now that you taught me what it does not mean, can I know what it means ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I shall gladly answer your question if you specify what *"it"* refers to in your last comment. We have used several symbols here and using pronouns makes the conversation ambiguous, since it is not clear what nouns these pronouns are standing for.

Comment: @AlexM.: I don't know what game you are playing. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

No. It just means that $\int x \, \mathrm{d}t = 0$.

Comment: Where are the probabilities ? And why do you say "No", then (presumably) confirm $\mathbb E(x)=0$ ?

Comment: I more or less just repeated the definition of expectation: $\mathbb E(x) = \int x \, \mathrm{d}t$. And the probability is covered in the measure w.r.t. we are integrating (cf. the definition of the $L^2$ inner product in the question).

Comment: So why do you explicitly reproduce $\mathbb E(x)=0$ and say "No" ? And what's the meaning of $t$ as a parameter ?

Comment: To future readers: this answer is perfectly fine, please do not rush like sheep to delete it, just because other people have. (Contrary to my usual behaviour, I have decided to upvote it in order to cancel the pending delete votes associated with it.) @YvesDaoust should think twice before downvoting and voting to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Probability Essentials by Jacod and Protter;
$E[X]=\int_\Omega X(\omega)dP(\omega)$ whenever the expression makes sense. If your random variable $X\in L^2(\Omega)$ then this simply means that $X$ has finite variance, following by Holder's Inequality and $\sigma(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.
For your queistion; $E[X]=0$ means that the integral $\int_{\Omega} X(\omega)dP(\omega)=0$. Using the expectation rule, if $X$ has a density, we can write this in Lebesgue-sense as $E[X]=\int_\mathbb{R} xf(x)d x$.

When you write $X(t)$, it smells like a stochastic process over $t\in [0,T]$, and should be properly defined. An example is the Wiener-Process $W(t)$, which actually has the property that $E[W(t)]=0$ for all $t\in [0,T]$.

You have to, sort of, think a little carefully when dealing with these things, and notation here makes a big difference. This might not help you directly, but clearify a few things. Sorry in advance if it only puts fire to the heavy debate above. I might have made a few technical missteps as well.